# How to Solve 502 Bad Gateway error in Nginx Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, nginx

I am getting the error code **502 Bad Gateway** in my Magento Installation with the following error in **error log**

> *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: v3.com, request: "GET
> /new-arrivals/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "v3.com"

How to solve this?

Comment: Hey you can go through below link this might help: [Bad Gateway 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844761/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream) If you find this answer helpful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137303)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @Pavithra

Comment: Please check this link https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon/782128
May be it helps you with your issue.

Answer (score 21):

I installed the magento2 when I am trying to open some pages facing 502 nginx issue,

in nginx logs it is showing

> upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream,

then solved this issue by modifying this file

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

add this line of codes inside `http{}`

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

for more details refer below link

https://bobcares.com/blog/magento-502-bad-gateway/?unapproved=75360&moderation-hash=21aca5cefbcdd86f62c492697cb64954#comment-75360

Comment: proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
these lines helps thanks man

Comment: Having this issue in Magento 2.4 . Adding these lines work, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Are you using NGINX? It seems there is misconfiguration with your server.
Try to add:

```
http {
  .... your config ...

  fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

Restart NGINX and after, the error related to the header size should be solved.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844761/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream

Comment: Awesome. It worked for me.

Comment: I confirm it workef for me

Answer (score 2):

I got same type issue for 502 Bad Gateway error in Nginx Magento 2

**sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log**

Content as Below:

FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist in  ClassReader.php:26

magento 2 checkout   upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client:  server: d  request: "POST /customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5lb25iYXphci5jb20vY2hlY2tvdXQv/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.x-fpm.sock:", host: "dev.eonbazar.com", referrer: " /checkout/" ....etc

I solved my issue update my magento nginx config

Replace #Line with below two line

```
#fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k; 
fastcgi_buffers 11024 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

[image]