# Error 502 or Nginx takes over

Tags: magento2, nginx, npm, php8.1

---

**Magento Installation and Network Setup:**

Magento 2.4.6-ps2 (server) with elasticsearch 5.8 (docker) on NGINX server is successfully installed and running on an Oracle Cloud network environment, consisting of the following components:

**Server 1: Nginx Server; Nginx Proxy Manager**

- Public subnet of the network
- IP: 150.xxx.xx.xx4

**Server 2:**

- Nginx Server
- Magento 2.4.6-ps2 (server)
- Elasticsearch (running in Docker)
- IP: 1x.x.x.xx4 (Private IP)

**MySQL DB System:**

- Connectivity to the MySQL database is verified and working correctly.

**DNS and Network Configuration:**

**Cloudflare:**

```
A
server1
150.xxx.xx.xx4

Proxied

CNAME
kiqlik.com
server1.kiqlik.com
```

The same settings apply to `www.kiqlik.com`.

The DNS is tested, kibana has worked, magento should also do.

**NPM UI Configuration:**

- Kibana is accessible via http://1x.x.x.xx4:5601.
- Magento should be accessible at http://1x.x.x.xx4:8000.

**Inside Server 2 (Magento Server):**

**Step 1: Composer Configuration:**

```bash
composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public-key> <private-key>
# Make sure to replace <public-key> and <private-key> with your actual keys.
# This step is complete with the correct keys.
```

**Hosts File Configuration:**

```bash
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
ff02::3         ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1       webserver-magento-poc   webserver-magento-poc
127.0.0.1       kiqliq.com www.kiqlik.com
# Your Cloudflare DNS records
1xx.xxx.xxx.xx4 kiqliq.com www.kiqlik.com
```

**Nginx Configuration (Magento Site):**

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento

upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; # Use the correct socket path
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name kiqlik.com www.kiqlik.com;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

    # Logging - adjust paths as necessary
    access_log /var/log/nginx/magento_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/magento_error.log;

    # PHP-FPM configuration
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend; # Use the upstream defined above
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # You can also add other optimizations or configurations here as needed.
}
```

Also tried new installation with these:

```
server {
    listen 8000;  # Listen on port 80 (HTTP). You can use a different port if needed.
    server_name kiqlik.com;  # Replace with your domain name.

    # Define the document root where your Magento files are located.
    root /var/www/html/2.4.6-p2;

    # Magento requires these settings for PHP processing.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;  # Adjust the PHP-FPM socket path.
    }

    # Other Nginx configuration directives as needed.
    # You can add SSL configuration for HTTPS support here if you have an SSL certificate.
}
```

and

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {

  listen 8000;
  server_name www.kiqlik.com kiqlik.com;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/2.4.6-p2;
  include /var/www/html/2.4.6-p2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

After configuring Nginx, the following commands were executed:

```bash
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

**PHP-FPM Socket Verification:**

```bash
ls /run/php
# Output:
# php-fpm.sock  php8.1-fpm.pid  php8.1-fpm.sock
```

Here's the `env.php` file with sensitive information redacted:

```php
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin_1e6oxw'
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'graphql' => [
            'id_salt' => 'aa1Ng1yTtlw7oP7uYkKlB3A0PLJxjgg4'
        ],
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'id_prefix' => 'd19_'
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'id_prefix' => 'd19_'
            ]
        ],
        'allow_parallel_generation' => false
    ],
    'remote_storage' => [
        'driver' => 'file'
    ],
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '6ede5f69c070f0c1469e5a3a23bcdd98'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual host
                'dbname' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual database name
                'username' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual username
                'password' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual password
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ],
    'lock' => [
        'provider' => 'db'
    ],
    'directories' => [
        'document_root_is_pub' => true
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1
    ],
    'downloadable_domains' => [
        'kiqlik.com'
    ],
    'elasticsearch' => [
        'server_hostname' => 'localhost',
        'server_port' => '9200',
        'enable_auth' => '0',
        'username' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual Elasticsearch username
        'password' => 'REDACTED', // Replace with your actual Elasticsearch password
        'index_prefix' => 'magento2',
        'timeout' => '15',
        'verify_host' => '1'
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Thu, 05 Oct 2023 03:53:58 +0000'
    ],
];
```

```
deborah@webserver-magento-poc:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1       webserver-magento-poc   webserver-magento-poc
127.0.0.1       kiqliq.com www.kiqlik.com
# The proxy host on npm
150.{vvv}4 www.kiqlik.com kiqlik.com
```

```
ubuntu@webserver-magento-poc:~$ curl -Ik https://kiqlik.com/admin_n5lu4r --insecure
HTTP/2 502 
server: openresty
date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 21:35:24 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 154
```

[image: dns]

[image: npm]

This is the milion'th time I install this and now that I finally got elasticsearch no alive nodes out the way, I get the proxy host file problem.

Last move was to re-install magento, use the default env.php with no elasticsearch lines, it is good, no errors, and it is installed.

I also did not create any set apart host file on sites-availabe, having only the etc/host with the proxy IP for npm.

502 Bad Gateway.

If I set the sites-availabe Nginx takes the 8000.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

modifying this file

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

add this line of codes inside `http{}`

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243248/how-to-solve-502-bad-gateway-error-in-nginx-magento-2

Comment: Thanks MP, I added, also tried again the sites-avalable and sites enebled above. Return: Welcome to nginx!